# Correlation between a continuous variable and a sparse integer variable

Tags: correlation, descriptive-statistics

I seek a correlation between 2 columns, X and Y.

- X is a continuous variable
- Y is an integer, but most of its values are zero

I have several hundred rows of data for the two columns.

The Pearson correlation coefficient between them is understandably low.  However, is there another type of correlation that I can use when there is significant sparsity in the integral variable?

Comment: The Y variable is obscure. Is it categorical nominal or ordinal or count or (discrete) metric? What does zero mean there and why is the variable sparse?

Comment: No, it's not.  I stated clearly that it is an integer, so it's obviously not categorical or ordinal.

Zero means 0, the number.  Most of its values are zero.  Sparse is just a brief way of saying that a matrix, vector, or data set has mostly zeros.

Comment: You really need to give more context for this to be answerable. What is that integer variable measuring? Can you show us a plot? a table of its values? ...

Comment: I agree with the others that context matters. Not only do we need to know what the variables are, but we need to know what you are trying to describe; lots of people use the term "correlation" rather loosely. Do you mean any type of association? Do you want to look at the relationship excluding the 0 values? or what?

Comment: No, I don't need to give you any more context.  The question itself is perfectly clear.  I want some estimator of correlation between a continuous variable and an integer variable, and the integer variable happens to have many zeros.  No, I don't mean association.  I mean correlation.  Treat this as a theoretical question, if you must.  As a possible example, how do you estimate the correlation between income and the number of vacation homes that a household buys?  Most households don't buy vacation homes; they're struggling with the mortgages of their principal residences already.